# How to save the canvas in tkinter in pdf format?

Tags: python, image, pdf, tkinter, postscript

I want to save the entire canvas (created in tkinter) including the scrollable region with high quality and convert into pdf/HD Image. Could you please help  me to solve this issue ?

I tried to use postscript but it is not including the scrollable region and the quality is very low..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the PIL library to take a screenshot, I threw some code together, it's not perfect just an example.

Things I would improve, load the form first and take screenshot in another thread once the frame has loaded. Get location of the frame and pass it to take_screenshot().

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageGrab

def take_screenshot():
    # Take a screenshot of the Tkinter window
    image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(50, 50, 600, 500))
    image.save("screenshot.png")

# Create a new Tkinter window
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('600x400+50+50')

# Add a label to the winow
label = tk.Label(window, text="Enter your name:")
label.pack()

# Add a text field to the window
text_field = tk.Entry(window)
text_field.pack()

# Add a submit button to the window
submit_button = tk.Button(window, text="Submit")
submit_button.pack()

# Take a screenshot of the Tkinter window
take_screenshot()

# Start the Tkinter event loop
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i tried this option it is just taking the screenshot of the only visible portion but i need to save the entire canvas which includes the scroll region.